# WPF Command Not Executing

Tags: c#, wpf

My main window is currently displaying the YearView in a content control via DataTemplated  YearViewModel. When I click the month button on the YearView I want the main window to instead display the MonthView. The MainViewModel (view model of the main window not shown) retrieves the view model to be displayed from '_navigationStorage.CurrentViewModel' as seen in NavigateMonthCommand.Execute(). But when I click the month button, NavigateMonthCommand.Execute() is never called.

Is the month button binding not working? In YearView.xaml should I be specifying the DataContext differently?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Calandar.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Calandar.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Calandar.Views"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Calandar"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="LightSlateGray">
    
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:YearViewModel}">
                    <views:YearView/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:MonthViewModel}">
                    <views:MonthView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

YearView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Calandar.Views.YearView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Calandar.Views"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Calandar.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="White" DataContext="viewmodels:YearViewModel">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Year" FontSize="55"/>
            <Button Content="Month" Command="{Binding NavigateMonthCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

YearViewModel.cs

```
public class YearViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public ICommand NavigateMonthCommand { get; }

    public YearViewModel(NavigationStorage navigationStorage)
    {
        NavigateMonthCommand = new NavigateMonthCommand(navigationStorage);
    }

}
```

NavigateMonthCommand.cs

```
public class NavigateMonthCommand : CommandBase
{

    private readonly NavigationStorage _navigationStorage;

    public NavigateMonthCommand(NavigationStorage navigationStorage)
    {
        _navigationStorage = navigationStorage;
    }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ;
        _navigationStorage.CurrentViewModel = new MonthViewModel();
    }

}
```

CommandBase.cs

```
public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

    public abstract void Execute(object parameter);

    public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Commandbase user defined?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen im not really sure what that means, but I added the class into the question.

Comment: Minor tip: replace `new EventArgs()` with `EventArgs.Empty`, save a class instantion.

Answer (score 0):

[**Look this one**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0)

Without `iNotifyPropertyChanged` Viewmodel cannot get data from view interface. You must connect properly. You should derive `ViewModelBase` from `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I think you have created your BaseViewModel, you can create the method there.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;         
public void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)         
{             
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
}
```

you need to call it while doing property set operation in the YearViewModel you specified. Sample:

```
        private string surName;
        public string SurName
        {
            get { return surName; }
            set { surName = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SurName)); }
        }
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you. I read the documentation. But where would I call OnPropertyChanged()?

Comment: @oopsHithere  I think you have created your `BaseViewModel`, you can create the method there. `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }`

Comment: Ok, but where should I call that method so that the ViewModel can get data from the view?

Comment: you need to call it while doing property set operation in the ViewModel you specified. Sample:   `private string surName;
        public string SurName
        {
            get { return surName; }
            set { surName = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SurName)); }
        }`

Comment: when you're done with your question, i detail the answers comment :D

Comment: Im glad you brought iNotifyPropertyChanged up, but I am not trying to 'set' anything (yet). I am trying to execute the NavigateMonthCommand in the YearViewModel.

Comment: I looked at your code again. I found that iCommand `NavigateMonthCommand` is ambiguous. it should be: `public ICommand NavigateMonthCommand => new NavigateMonthCommand(this) `